# Python times tables code with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have to make a times table code using recursive functions. I have to ask the user for a number and print out the times tables from 1 to 12. And I have to use recursive functions and it is not allowed to use `for` loops or `while` loops and all variables besides the user input have to be defined inside the functions. I am having trouble defining the number that the user provided number needs to be multiplied with. E.X. 2 x **1** 2 x **2** 2 x **3**.

```
def times_tables(num):
    def multiply(x):
        product = x * num
    if x < 12:
        print (str(multiply(x + 1)))

user = input("Enter a number: ")
times_tables(user)
```

If I define `x` in the `times_tables` function then every time the function runs it will get set back to whatever I set it to the first time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I recall recursion well, I think you have to set up conditions. Start with the base case. Simplist step. And then have the next step (2nd simplest step) reference the result of the simplest step. And go from there.

Comment: You never modifying x, you are not returning any thing from multiply(x)

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying x, x is passed by value, this mean it is copied.

If you want to keep the exit conditon outside the recursion you need a way to write X directly from the recursion, which probably would involve a global (bad practices so avoid).

You need to have the exit condition inside multiply, because that will be your recursion, in that case your X will increase and you will do the check on the proper incremented value. Or change the function all together as ruggfrancesco suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
def times_tables(n, t=1):
    if t == 13:
        return
    print(str(n) + " x " + str(t) + " = " + str(n*t))
    times_tables(n, t+1)

times_tables(int(input("Enter number: ")))

Enter number: 3
3 x 1 = 3
3 x 2 = 6
3 x 3 = 9
3 x 4 = 12
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
3 x 8 = 24
3 x 9 = 27
3 x 10 = 30
3 x 11 = 33
3 x 12 = 36
```

Answer (score 0):

When I (Image) Google "times table", I get a very different result from what the other answers produce.  Below is my recursive solution in *two* dimensions:

```
def times_table(limit):
    number_format = "{{:{}}}".format(len(str(limit ** 2)))

    def times_table_recursive(number, increment):
        minimum = max(increment, 1)

        if number <= minimum * limit:
            print(number_format.format(number if number > 0 else 'x'), end=' ')
            times_table_recursive(number + minimum, increment)
        elif increment < limit:
            print()
            increment += 1
            print(number_format.format(increment), end=' ')
            times_table_recursive(increment, increment)
        else:
            print()

    times_table_recursive(0, 0)

times_table(12)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
x     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
  1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
  2   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24 
  3   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36 
  4   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48 
  5   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60 
  6   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72 
  7   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84 
  8   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96 
  9   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108 
 10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 
 11  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132 
 12  12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144 
>
```

Only goes up to `times_table(30)` without expanding Python's recursion depth limit.

Answer (score -1):

```
def fun (no,i=1):
     if i==10:
          print (no*i)
     else:
          print (no*fun(i+1)
no=int (input ("Enter a no="))
fun (no)
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This answer isn't correct.  A missing parenthesis on line 5 keeps it from running.  Once that's fixed, a failure to pass the arguments correctly to the recursive call causes it to stack overflow.  It does a multiplication against the result of `fun()` which always returns `None`.  Complete misstep.